# How to print a discord.py bot error terminal (CLI) in the discord chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to be printing all the error commands and the application logs into the chat, (basically whatever comes in my terminal when the bot runs), into a specific channel in my server, is there any way to do it? Error handlers wont be useful here, would they be?

Comment: Can you post the code? Not that easy to help you without it.

Comment: the code is huge, lets pretend, im sending in !test in the chat, the bot wont recognize it as a command and send this error in the cli ``discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "`!test" is not found`` i want this error to be posted in a specific channel in my server

Comment: you can try handling an exception and then loggin that exception and/or printing it in that specific channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [discord.py Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_error) and [Event Command Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#event-reference), it allows you to create error handlers

An example for a `on_error` event handler which sends the traceback to it's owner:

````
import discord

import traceback
import datetime

@bot.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=':x: Event Error', colour=0xe74c3c) #Red
    embed.add_field(name='Event', value=event)
    embed.description = '```py\n%s\n```' % traceback.format_exc()
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await bot.AppInfo.owner.send(embed=embed)
````